# My Navbar Does not appear

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am doing this on Codepen,
A dark-color navbar should appear with my name in a light color, but it does not happen. I am following the guide of bootstrap 4.0 that is online.

I have included all the necessary classes as per the guide and examples that i read.

```
<div id="entire" class="container-fluid">

  <div id="topbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-brand navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <h1>Vishwad Desai</h1>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="actual">
    <p> Start</p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKWTb.jpg)

Comment: Did you import the bootstrap js and css ?

Comment: Read the [docs for the navbar](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#how-it-works), and use the appropriate "supported content".

Comment: I came across Codepen via freeCodeCamp, there is a setting(as guided by FCC), where it allows automatic addition of bootstrap, as I understood that it automatically links bootstrap to the code, i.e there is no need to include all those lines for linking Code Delivery Network. Now it seems i did not understand what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure to include all the [necessary CSS and JS files](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Additional you have to set the class `.navbar-brand` to the `<h1>` element directly (not to the `<nav>`). See the following working example:

```html
<!-- include all the required CSS and JS files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- your code -->
<div id="entire" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="topbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <h1 class="navbar-brand">Vishwad Desai</h1>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="actual">
    <p> Start</p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, it seems that the problem is on the part of automatic addition of bootstrap, it has not been done.